# Make SWIG generate python 3.2 print() statements

Tags: python-3.x, swig

I have feeling there's a very simple answer to this.

I'm trying to generate a python 3.2 SWIG wrapper.  SWIG is supposed to work with 3.2, and everything works great, and the DLL is built.  But, when I try to import my module I get:

```
>>> import pywii
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pywii.py", line 645
    print 'Searching for wiimotes... Turn them on!'
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, SWIG is clearly generating Python 2 code.  How do I make it do Python 3 instead?  Thanks.

Comment: SWIG doesn't generate Python code, it generates C-code that creates a library you can import from Python. So this all seems highly unlikely to be a SWIG problem.

Comment: @Lennart, SWIG does generate Python class wrappers.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Aha, I didn't know that. Even so, those wrappers should not print anything. I think Ian needs to show exactly how he generates the failing code, so it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised a SWIG-generated Python file would use `print`.  Are you sure that is part of the generated Python wrapper?  The generated wrapper should work with both Python 2 and Python 3, but there is one Python 3-specific switch (`-py3`) that enables some Python 3 features.